# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Tags: nltk

***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'***

````
sentence = "Какой был шквал?"
tokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
pos_tagged = pos_tag(tokenized, lang='rus')
print(pos_tagged)
key_words = []
for word, pos in pos_tagged:
    if pos == 'V' or pos == 'S':
        key_words.append(word)
    print(key_words)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Open shell and install nltk.

```
pip install nltk
```

Open the python interactive shell by typing python in terminal. Install the punkt and averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru packages.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru')
```

Run the following code.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentence = "Какой был шквал?"
tokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
pos_tagged = pos_tag(tokenized, lang='rus')
print(pos_tagged)
key_words = []
for word, pos in pos_tagged:
    if pos == 'V' or pos == 'S':
        key_words.append(word)
    print(key_words)
```